# How to change assets urls between dev and prod environment inside html, js and less

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs

Having a big web project (single page app) with relative urls for assets inside the html, js and less files. (assets being images, fonts, flash component, etc..)

When deployed, the assets are reside in a different domain (CDN) than the html/js/css files.

How can I easily change urls when going to production environment?

I thought about trying to move all urls to the less(css) files, not having any of them in html/js, and then define a less-variable for the 'base' url and use it as prefix for every url.
This is very limiting because sometimes having the url in html is preferable (e.g. img elements).

Or using Grunt with grunt-string-replace and have a placeholder everywhere that will be replaced with the base url.

Another option is inlining these assets. Ruled out this option because it results in huge files (css/js > 1MB) which will be heavy on the page load.

Is there a way which will do it automatically, without having the need to think about it while developing?

Comment: Have you tried making configuration on server for this? you can define RewriteRule in host file which will redirect to specific server for specific request.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar is it only relevant for apache? and it seems to have a time penalty, because every request results in a redirect response which trigger another request from the browser to server2.

Comment: either way, browser is going to send separate request to server for each asset on client side. The reason I sugested server side configuration is, it is more secure. Doing same thing on client side, you many need to define variable which will contain URL and other stuff. It usually is not time taking since the request is not redirecting, its all together new request, the only difference will be, it will have different origin.